# MongoDB Aggregate, Project and Match

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've managed to create an aggregate query to retrieve records and its count, grouped by year.

My current query

```
db.records.aggregate([
        {"$project": {"_id": 0, "date": {"$dateFromString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d", "dateString": "$when"}}}},
        {"$group": {"_id": {"$year": "$date"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$sort": {"_id": 1}}
])
```

My collection

```
{
    "id": "123456", 
    "when": "2021-01-01"

}
```

How do I alter my current query to retrieve all records and its count in a given year and have it grouped by months?

Sample output

```
[{'_id': 01, 'count': 15}, {'_id': 02, 'count': 53}, {'_id': 03, 'count': 64}, {'_id': 04, 'count': 44}, {'_id': 05, 'count': 42}, {'_id': 06, 'count': 129}, {'_id': 07, 'count': 170}, {'_id': 08, 'count': 148}, {'_id': 09, 'count': 67}, {'_id': 10, 'count': 67}, {'_id': 11, 'count': 67}, {'_id': 12, 'count': 50}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually on the right track. After converting the date string to date, just use `$year` to perform the filtering and use `$month` in `$group` to do the group and count.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          "dateString": "$when"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            "$year": "$date"
          },
          2021
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $month: "$date"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KgqCE7PE1t4) for your reference.

One side note: storing date as string is considered as anti pattern and will make your query unnecessarily complicated. It is recommeneded to store them as proper date field.